# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, xampp

I'm using xammp **v3.2.2** in validate user I got this error:

`count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

I don't know that this error depends on xampp, yii2 or php v7.2.3.

```
in C:\xampp\htdocs\payesh\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\UniqueValidator.php at line 136

        if ($this->modelExists($targetClass, $conditions, $model)) {
            if (count($targetAttribute) > 1) { //error mentions here
                $this->addComboNotUniqueError($model, $attribute);
            } else {
                $this->addError($model, $attribute, $this->message);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my user model:

```
public function signup() {
     if ($this->validate()) { // the error mentions here too
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->email;
            $user->email = $this->email;
     if ($user->save(false)) {
                return $user;
    }
    }
```

this picture of error page might be useful to understand well:

[image: fist part of error]

rest of error page:

[image: rest of error page]

what do I have to do?

Comment: What exactly is $targetAttribute? The error sais it needs an array but ist is not.

Comment: show your validations where you have applied unique validator

Comment: @DieterKräutl I don't know, its on yii2

Comment: @NitinPund Can you tell me more? Do you mean my model rules?

Comment: yes, your model rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the last version of Yii2 (or 2.0.13 at least) - compatibility with PHP 7.2 was significantly improved in 2.0 13 release, see [this PR](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/14959).

But in general you should use last version of Yii if you're using last version of PHP - using outdated version of framework with most recent PHP version may bring many problems. Especially that PHP 7.2 brings many BC breaks and many things was broken in this version.

Comment: Are you sure if I upgrade my yii2 my problem will be removed?

Comment: Yes, you can see in linked PR that this line was changed in 2.0.13 release.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you so much. I upgrade to Yii 2.0.11 and my problem solved. of course in the first time in upgrading there was problem in composer updating, but in the second time upgraded it.